# How to randomly generate Tree or Nested List of Function in Mathematica?

Tags: programming, trees, meta-programming

In detail,
I want to generate randomly something like  
Divide[Add[X,Times[X,Y]],Times[X,3]]
or
{Divide,{Add,X,{Times{X,Y}}},{Times,X,3}}

(Specified Function(# of argument is from 2 to 5)) + Specified  Symbol+Random Integer)
,but I don't know how to implement this.
Are there any good example?

Comment: `TreeForm[(X + Y) (Z + W)]`?

Comment: No,I meant "Tree" is something like Func[X,Func2[Y]] ( Nested list of function?)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. _Mathematica_ expressions are already trees. Look at `ClearAll[x,y]; TreeForm[x + y]`!

Comment: Yes,Mathematica's expression is already tree. but I wanted to create "Tree" or "Expression" randomly for using meta-programming. For example, Tree(max-depth 2 & head is "Plus") is Plus[a1,a2]. I should have use something like "Nested Function" but "Tree", Anyway thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This version is a bit more involved than the other answers given above, but it respects the condition on the arities of the functions.

```
ClearAll[plus, times, div, m, f, g, h];
m = 5;
f[a_, n_] := Symbol[FromCharacterCode[96 + n] <> ToString@a];
g[a_, n_] /; (n <= 1) := f[a, n];
g[a_, n_] := Replace[RandomChoice[{1, 2}], {1 -> f[a, n], 2 -> h[a + m + 1, n - 1]}];
h[a_, n_] /; (n <= 1) := g[a, n];
h[a_, n_] := Replace[RandomChoice[{
    {plus, RandomInteger[{2, m}]}, {times, RandomInteger[{2, 5}]}, {div, 2}
}], {s_, t_} :> s @@ Map[g[a + #, n] &, Range@t]];
h[n_] := h[0, n];
```

Most of the awkwardness is due to the fact that the accumulator `a` tries to force the creation of a new symbol each time. You can test it as follows:

```
h[5] // FullForm
(*
    plus[e1, times[d9, div[c17, plus[a31, a32, b27, a34]], d11, times[c19, plus[a33, a34, b29, a36]]], div[d10, plus[plus[b25, b26, b27, a34, b29], plus[b26, a33]]], e4]
*)

h[3] // FullForm
(* div[plus[a14, a15, b10, a17], c2] *)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
B[B[A, A], B[A, A]] //. {B :> RandomChoice[{1, 1, 1, 1} -> {mult, div, add, sub}], A :> RandomChoice[{1, 1, 1, 1, 5} -> {mult[A, A], sub[A, A], div[A, A], add[A, A], RandomInteger[{1, 10}]}]}
```

I've made the initial condition non-trivial so that you'll always get a somewhat interesting result instead of, eg, just a number

> add[add[add[2, 7], 7],   div[mult[mult[2, 10], 5], add[div[add[1, 7],
>   10], 8]]]

Replace `add`, `div`, etc with `Plus`, `Divide`, ... for actual Mathematica expressions. As for variable argument lists, I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader!

Answer (score 1):

The following example might show you a way forward.  We define a recursive random function that builds a tree.

```
heads = {f, g};
factor = 0.9;
randomtree[mean_] := RandomChoice[heads]@@Table[randomtree[factor*mean], 
   RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[mean]]]

randomtree[2.2]
(* g[
 g[f[f[f[], 
    f[f[f[f[g[]], g[g[f[f[g[f[], f[]], g[]]], g[]], f[]]]]]]]]] *)
```